# cpuutilization alarm for multiple instances, insufficient data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I've created a CPU Utilization alarm with using anomaly detection, this shows a graph with expected cpu utilization (anomaly detection band) but the alarm shows "insufficient data" and no graphed line for cpuutilization.

`aws cloudwatch describe-alarms` gives the following output, showing configured metrics (with account ids removed)

```
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "AlarmName": "ec2-cpu-anomaly-detection-2",
            "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-2:xxxx:ec2-cpu-anomaly-detection-2",
            "AlarmDescription": "EC2 CPU usage anomaly detection, acct",
            "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2021-05-06T13:29:08.848Z",
            "ActionsEnabled": true,
            "OKActions": [],
            "AlarmActions": [],
            "InsufficientDataActions": [],
            "StateValue": "INSUFFICIENT_DATA",
            "StateReason": "Unchecked: Initial alarm creation",
            "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2021-05-06T13:29:08.848Z",
            "Dimensions": [],
            "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
            "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanUpperThreshold",
            "TreatMissingData": "missing",
            "Metrics": [
                {
                    "Id": "m1",
                    "MetricStat": {
                        "Metric": {
                            "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                            "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                            "Dimensions": []
                        },
                        "Period": 60,
                        "Stat": "Average",
                        "Unit": "Count"
                    },
                    "ReturnData": true
                },
                {
                    "Id": "e1",
                    "Expression": "ANOMALY_DETECTION_BAND(m1)",
                    "Label": "CPUUtilization (Expected)",
                    "ReturnData": true
                }
            ],
            "ThresholdMetricId": "e1"
        }
    ],
    "CompositeAlarms": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the dimension parameter is what connects the alarm to the metric.  the output of the dimension parameter here shows no content.  that means it has no connection to a metric and thus no graphed line.  The dimension output should look something like this:

```
        "Dimensions": [
            {
                "Name": "InstanceId",
                "Value": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "Name": "ImageId",
                "Value": "ami-xxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "Name": "path",
                "Value": "<partition path ie: /home>"
            },
            {
                "Name": "InstanceType",
                "Value": "<instance type ie: t2.small>"
            },
            {
                "Name": "device",
                "Value": "<device name ie:mapper/primary-home>"
            },
            {
                "Name": "fstype",
                "Value": "<filesystem type ie:ext4"
            }
        ],
```

if you look at the source of the metric you are trying to use, you will see the expected values.